# Can we simply decompose a multivariable equation as below?

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations

So, suppose I'm given the function $u(x,y) = v(x + \frac{y^2}{2}, y)$, I am supposed to prove that all solutions can be written in the form:

$$
u(x,y) = f(x + \frac{y^2}{2}) y + g(x + \frac{y^2}{2})
$$

Now I could solve this through differentiation methods as this was one of the final parts of the solving of a PDE by Change of Variables, however I'm looking at this and seeing that it looks a lot like the equation for a sloped line and the fact that y is passed through to the $v(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ without change.

Is there a simple solution here, or is the only method to differentiate this and subsitute into the original PDE?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense because it is missing context. You haven't even provided the PDE.

Comment: @MatthewCassell the PDE is of the form $A u_{xx} (x,t) - \frac{1}{t} u_{xt} (x,t) = 0$ I assumed that it wasn't necessary to include the PDE as it looks like it could be solvable with some element of logic due to the $y$ being passed through to the function $v$ from $u$.